# Jenkins plugin auto import

Tags: bash, jenkins

Fairly new to the use of Jenkins, but I am looking for a way to get test results and feed it back into Jenkins.

What this means is, I have a bash scripts that collects metrics on a number of applications and checks to see whether or not the files exist. I collect this data to a plain text file, basically with counters 1/5, 2/5, 5/10 etc.

The output can be however I want it, but I was wondering if there is a good/clean process that can take this data file and output it nicely inside of Jenkins web interface?

We also use Trac as well.. so if there is a Trac plugin that can do something similar, that would be good too.

Answer (score 0):

The best practices would say to escape them and use them as parameters to a parameterized jenkins build or a file save/capture. Parameters are finicky and subject to url encoding, so I would personally do file passing using a shared filesystem such as S3. Your best bet is https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API